# Down Arrow On Lists Within Lists

Tags: css

I'm trying to place a down-arrow in my navigation menu, if there is a `li` within an `li`.

Hover over the *Shop* link to see where I'm having difficulty - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ABucF

The arrow (or V for my demonstration purposes) should be just after the *Shop* tab, *Check Out* and *My Account*, not inside it.

How would I be able to achieve this in the CSS?

Thank you.

Comment: http://codepen.io/sahilpopli/pen/GcFCb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to look at an element to check for a specific condition and style its parent based on that.

CSS can't yet be used to style parent elements unfortunately.

Your best bet is to simply add a class onto each element you want styled and do it that way or to physically place an icon/img in each anchor tag that requires it.

Alternatively use JavaScript to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

give a class to the parent who has sub child in it i.e Shop

```
.parent:after{
content:"V";
//or
background:url(image.png) no-repeat position;

}
```

[updated pen](http://codepen.io/sahilpopli/pen/GcFCb)